# OpenAI API call error: we could not parse the JSON

Tags: json

Hi I’m trying to build an API call from openAI but sometimes i get this error

> There was an issue setting up your call.
> Raw response for the API
> Status code 400
> {
> “error”: {
> “message”: “We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren’t using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please send an email to support@openai.com and include any relevant code you’d like help with.)”,
> “type”: “invalid_request_error”,
> “param”: null,
> “code”: null
> }
> }

my API call is the following:

```
{
“model”: “text-davinci-003”,
“prompt”: “Q: can you explain to me this excel \n <excel_formula>\n”,
“temperature”: 0.22,
“max_tokens”: 500,
“top_p”: 1,
“frequency_penalty”: 0,
“presence_penalty”: 0
}
```

where excel_formula is set as INDEX(A1:D10, MATCH(“maximum”, A1:D10, 0), MATCH(“January”, A1:D1, 0))

I suppose that as I'm wrapping maximum in the same quotes as the whole value so it's ending it there and messing it up.

any tip on how we can solve this? I would like to keep the "" around

I'm stucked, not sure what to do

Comment: You have to replace " “ ", with " " ";

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put this text into the comments , but it doesn't support rich formatting.

You have to replace

```
 “ and ”
```

with

```
"
```

Comment: I tried to edit this to add a little clarity, because I initially misread it as "you have to replace `"and"` with `"`" and was confused. My suggested edit got rejected, so I posted as a new answer. If you feel like updating this answer I'm happy to delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the smart quotes (“) with straight quotes ("):

```
"model": "text-davinci-003",
"prompt": "Q: can you explain to me this excel \n <excel_formula>\n",
"temperature": 0.22,
"max_tokens": 500,
"top_p": 1,
"frequency_penalty": 0,
"presence_penalty": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just pass "**json=data**" in header so its works for me:

> Error

```
 {“message”: “We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren’t using your HTTP library correctly}
```

> Fix in Python:

```
   data = {
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "messages": [
    {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
  ]
}

requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

> Output

```
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-ID :)",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1685801561,
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 13,
        "completion_tokens": 26,
        "total_tokens": 39
    },
    "choices": [
        {
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "I apologize, but you have not specified what \"it\" refers to. Could you please provide more context or clarify your question?"
            },
            "finish_reason": "stop",
            "index": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

**My Prompt:**

```
User Input: - "Write short note on pollution"
```

When I replace" "  with ' ' it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After up and down, Finally what works for me was I converted the json data to string before sending it, maybe openAi want object in string format

Example on javascript

`//this is the json data that i want to send`

`let data = {"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role":"user","content":"what is your name?"}],"temperature":0.7};`

`// this is the data i will finally post to the Api`
`let finalData = JSON.stringify(data);`

//its work fast